# How to emit / raise events in a custom React-native component?

Tags: react-native

How do you raise and respond to events in a custom component?

```
//In the main.js
<MyComponent onSomething={this.handleSomething} />
```

I have no idea what the code would look like inside of "MyComponent"... have tried a few things, read the docs and downloaded the react native source.

Tried `this.props.onSomething` but i get a "not an object" error.

Comment: <MyComponent onSomething={() => {this.handleSomething()}} /> and call it like this : this.props.onSomething()

Comment: awesome that works!